# How is hoisting possible in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How does **JavaScript perform hoisting** if it is an interpreted language. Doesn't interpreted languages execute code from top to bottom line by line. Is there any type of compilation working in the background?

Comment: JavaScript is compiled by the browser, not interpreted line-by-line. That's why syntax errors stop the whole thing working as opposed to getting that far before giving up.

Comment: I'm sure each of the main javascript engines performs the task in a different way - I drive a car every day, I don't need to know how an internal combustion engine works to do so

Comment: "if it is an interpreted language"  — It isn't. Your question is based on a false premise.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol So is JavaScript a compiled language or an interpreted one?

Comment: Javascript is *a language*. It can be compiled by a compiler or interpreted by an interpreter. The most prevalent use of Javascript these days is via an interpreter.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks for the clarification :) I had come upon some articles and blogs which claimed JavaScript to be a dynamic interpreted language and thus was curious how it handled things such as hoisting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Interpreted" does not mean that each line is executed immediately as it is being read. The Javascript interpreter first reads *the entire file*, a process during which it parses the information into executable code. Hoisting is happening here: between *parsing* and *execution*.

---

In a nutshell and very simplified, hoisting works like this:

- parser/interpreter reads the source code into an intermediate representation
- some keywords introduce new scopes (e.g. `function`), for which a new "scope object" will be created*
- if during the parsing of a scope the parser encounters a `var` keyword (or other related keywords), it creates that symbol name on the current scope (with no value/`undefined`)

<sub>** Don't read too much into the word "object" here, it's not Javascript we talk about, but the intermediate language Javascript is being compiled to.*</sub>

So after this process, you've got some intermediary representation of your source code, in which scopes are defined **and local symbol names are reserved on it.** That's how variable names are *hoisted* to "the top" before any code has actually been executed.

Comment: Is this something like a partial compilation, like Java which produces bytecodes and then gets interpreted?

Comment: How exactly it works is up to each individual engine, but generally: yes. It is parsed/compiled into a more basic intermediate language, and depending on the engine it may then be compiled even further with more optimisations later on; for instance if the engine notices a particular piece of code being invoked very often, more in-depth compilation may take place in the background to optimise that particular piece of code for maximum performance.

Comment: Javascript engines are *very* complex beasts these days…

Comment: Hi, Muhammad Aref also gave me an answer regarding this and I find it quite convincing but someone has marked it negatively without giving any reason could you please tell me if the answer is valid.

Comment: @Amarjit I've added a simplified explanation of the hoisting process.

Answer (score 1):

Interpreted languages / script languages doesn't just execute top to bottom. What "interpreted language" or "script language" mean is that there is no compiling to an binary or equal. You write the text and this script will directly be executed.

Depending on wich language you're choosing, it will have `functions` or `classes` or even `loops` and then it starts to not just execupte from top to bottom.

Answer (score -1):

The script is executed in two phases, in the first phase the interpreter will read the whole file, and just execute the **left side** definitions  of each expression...

`var x = 5`

Here, at the first phase, the interpreter will execute the left side `var x`, so it will find the current scope and define a variable called `x`.

During the second phase, it'll execute the **right side** of the expression and `x` will equal `5`

That's how the hoisting is done in JavaScript.

---

So in JS you can define a function be two ways:

- **Function declaration:** (The function is defined by `function` keyword) so it is in the left side, and will be hoisted.
- **Function expression:** (The function is defined by assigning a function to a variable) so the variable only will by hoisted, and the assignment will be at the second phase.

So let's show that in action:

```
// This example will work
test();
function test () {
    alert('test');
}
```

And,

```
// This example will raise an error
test();
var test = function () {
    alert();
}
```

Because in the second example, `test` will equal `undefined`, because the function hasn't been assigned to the `test` variable yet.

Comment: Oh! so that's how it is done. A two phase interpretation. What happens when i define a variable named **test** and a function **test** what will **test** represent after hoisting?

Comment: @Amarjit_3991 Could you show what you mean by some code, it's not clear.

Comment: var test = 'some value';
function test() {
    \\statements;
}
Here after hoisting what is test: a function or string?

Comment: The value of the variable `test` depends on where you are calling it! if you are calling it before this line, you will have `undefined` because the variable itself is hoisted, but the values hasn't been assigned yet

Comment: @Amarjit_3991It will be `'some value'`, because at the second phase, the assignment will overwrite the function

Comment: Oh! Thank you for the clarification :)

Comment: @Amarjit_3991welcome, and you can accept the answer if it clarifies your question!

Comment: Whoever  gave this answer a negative could you please explain why?

Comment: Not all left hand sides of expressions can be evaluated in that "first pass"; `foo[bar] = baz` can only be evaluated at runtime, not before. And no, there's no special case for these cases, the truth is it simply doesn't work like this.

Comment: @deceze Yes just the left side definitions

Comment: Following the example @deceze gave, we will get a **type error** if it is evaluated the way it is said in the answer as bar will be undefined during the first pass and foo[bar] should break the program. Isn't it?

Comment: The `foo` isn't neither an array nor an object, it's undefined, so you will get this error `VM422:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '...' of undefined`